# Second Harddrive is failing. Due to Hibernation?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, hibernate, hard-drive-failure

About a year ago my WD Green drive started failing. I started getting BSOD (disk related) and freezes, until it was not readable anymore. It was still recognized in the bios, but it was not mountable in windows and neither in ubuntu. Smart said btw it was flooded with bad sectors. So I plugged it out and bought a new one. WD Blue this time. It was working just fine until a couple of weeks ago.

What happens? If my computer is on, it works without any issues. But if I put it out. It won't start a couple of times. Scratchy Noises appear and after a while the "Select a proper boot device" message appears, repeatedly, if I hit a key to search again. When I boot ubuntu from USB Stick, it probably can't mount the drive. 
But after some rebooting or waiting in the ubuntu, the drive wakes up and works just fine again. 
SMART says again there are bad sectors...

```
-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 200 200 _51 0000000000A8 Read Error Rate
03 161 160 _21 000000001B1D Spin-Up Time
04 100 100 __0 000000000349 Start/Stop Count
05 200 200 140 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 200 200 __0 000000000000 Seek Error Rate
09 _95 _95 __0 000000000ECE Power-On Hours
0A 100 100 __0 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0B 100 100 __0 000000000000 Recalibration Retries
0C 100 100 __0 00000000033A Power Cycle Count
C0 200 200 __0 00000000006F Power-off Retract Count
C1 194 194 __0 000000004C6E Load/Unload Cycle Count
C2 124 108 __0 00000000001A Temperature
C4 200 200 __0 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
C5 200 200 __0 000000000003 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 200 200 __0 000000000003 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
C8 198 198 __0 000000000216 Write Error Rate
```

So, I'm expecting, that the drive does only fix the bad sectors, when it boots up. Thats probably, why I get the consecutive boot failures on startup, until some point it has nothing to fix anymore. But for your information, the "Uncorrectable Sector Count" did not get any higher from the last occurence to now.

I am thinking about buying another new harddrive (no WD this time). But I just want to ask, if there could be anything causing this issue. I never move my computer. I am using hibernation A LOT (writing RAM to Disk and turning it off). I just had some trouble with my GPU not working anymore. That was temporary too.

Comment: Just a thought but is it the same cable on both? hibernation or constant writes generally shouldn't cause this. Is this a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: Its a desktop and I tried 3 different sata cables... its sata II btw